# Ayuda con una expresión regular

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito hacer una expresión regular que me ayude a formatear un numero de esta manera.

**Ejemplo:** 
Tenemos este numero `222345678`

Necesito una expresión que pueda hacer esto: `22 234 5678`

Es decir, después de los primeros 2 números añadir un espacio, luego añadir uno después de los siguientes 3 y que el ultimo bloque quede en 4 números.

Actualmente tengo algo como esto: `number.toString().replace(/\d{4,4}?(?=...)/g, "$& ")`

El cual solo los separa cada 4.

He buscado alguna expresión que haga lo mismo pero no encuentro nada, alguien sabe como hacerla ? 
De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con grupos de captura:

```
number.toString().replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{4})/g, "$1 $2 $3")
```

Resultado: `22 234 5678`

Comment: Wow, muchisimas gracias.